# Bug in error handling logic in google.cloud.ml.dataflow.batch_prediction.PredictionDoFn

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm looking at the latest version (`obtained from gs://cloud-ml/sdk/cloudml-0.1.9-alpha.dataflow.tar.gz`)

On lines 153-159 of `google/cloud/ml/dataflow/batch_prediction.py`, we have the following code:

```
except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
  logging.error("Got an unknown exception: [%s].", traceback.format_exc())
  if self._cloud_logger:
    self._cloud_logger.write_error_message(
        str(e), self._create_snippet(context.element))
  yield beam.pvalue.SideOutputValue("errors",
                                    (e.error_message, context.element))
```

However, the Exception object `e` may not have the attribute `error_message`. This occasionally gives me errors like the following:

- `AttributeError: 'exceptions.RuntimeError' object has no attribute 'error_message' [while running 'Evaluate/ParDo(PredictionDoFn)']`
- `AttributeError: 'exceptions.KeyError' object has no attribute 'error_message' [while running 'Evaluate/ParDo(PredictionDoFn)']`
- etc

I assume these errors should not be raised, because the whole point of the except block is to catch those errors and pass them out of the ParDo as a side output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We've fixed it and a good version should be available in next release very soon.